# How to clear the memory of Cognos 10.1.1?

Tags: cognos-10

When I configure new database into the COGNOS. I got a message "Connection failed" due to password miss matching. When I entered correct username and password then hit test the connection. It will show incorrect password. I had changed password before test the configuration button. It shown an error message connection failed. Please help me how to rectify this error? Here i'm using DB2 database. I had cleared my browser history, cookies and password but still i got same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely to be a 'memory' retention issue.
Check the cogserver.log file within /logs and check what the error message is.

What is the exact error message you're getting when you try to test the connection?

Comment: Hi Scott, I didn't get any error message code while test the connection and    I was configured ODBC and CLI Driver good manner but still i got the same problem "connection failed".